# How to test a function that has calldata parameters using Foundry?

Tags: solidity, testing, calldata, foundry

I am trying to test out a function similar to the one shown below:

```
function add (Complex calldata x, Complex calldata y) pure returns (Complex memory result) {
    result = Complex(x.a.add(y.a), x.b.add(y.b));
}
```

If the storage type of the parameters is `memory`, I have no issues. However, if the storage type is `calldata`, I cannot declare this type of parameters for the function, because I get this:

**Type struct Complex memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct Complex calldata**

The testing function is shown below:

```
function testAdd(int256 a1, int256 b1, int256 a2, int256 b2) external {
    Complex memory x = Complex(SInteger.wrap(a1), SInteger.wrap(b1));
    Complex memory y = Complex(SInteger.wrap(a2), SInteger.wrap(b2));

    ...

    // The two statements below produce: Type struct Complex memory is not implicitly
    // convertible to expected type struct Complex calldata   
     
    Complex calldata actual = x.add(y); 
    Complex calldata expected = Complex(SInteger.wrap(a1).add(SInteger.wrap(a2)), SInteger.wrap(b1).add(SInteger.wrap(b2)));

    assertEq(SInteger.unwrap(actual.a), SInteger.unwrap(expected.a));
    assertEq(SInteger.unwrap(actual.b), SInteger.unwrap(expected.b));
}
```

If I do instead declare `x` and `y` using `memory`, then the following is shown:

**Member “add” not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct Complex memory.**

Answer (score 0):

Calldata is the cheapest type of storage, is read-only and can only be used for data passed into a function through the transaction input. So, it is impossible for you to modify `Complex calldata actual` or `Complex calldata expected`.

The solution is pretty simple, declare `Calldata` parameters as `memory` only for preparing the input params for the function to be tested and then pass it to the function, you do not need to convert it to `calldata` (not that it can be in the first place).

If you're calling the contract through a transaction, this will simply copy the `calldata` to the `memory`.